# Missing a closing quote for the string value

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the following line of code in my page.

```
<div class="master-page">
```

VS 2013 then marks it with 2 warnings

- Missing a closing quote for the string value.
- Missing a colon (':')
  between the property and value in the "(property) : (value)"
  declaration.

The CSS looks like this

```
div.master-page
{
    padding: 10px;
}

div.master-page div.master-page
{
    position: relative;
    margin: -20px;
}
```

Here is an image of the error[image]

How do I fix the warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting the line and type it again. Does work for me, if there is really no error.

Comment: This actually fixed it... OMS